# Return View From Controller in Area Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

After reading several posts on this subject I have yet to find an answer to my problem.  I have an MVC 3 application and have added an Area to it.  Everything works great until I try an return a view from a controller within the Area.

I can successfully post to the controllers Save Method but upon simply returning the view (return View()) I get the following:

The view 'Save' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:

```
~/Areas/Test/Views/Default1/Save.aspx
~/Areas/Test/Views/Default1/Save.ascx
~/Areas/Test/Views/Shared/Save.aspx
~/Areas/Test/Views/Shared/Save.ascx
...
```

This seems so basic, not sure why I am running into so much trouble.

Ive used Phil Haack's RouteDebugger (http://nuget.org/packages/routedebugger) and all routes are working as setup...

Comment: I notice you're using an Area.  Are you sure the Save.xxxx file is in the Area Views folder and not in the parent applications Areas folder?  Obviously there is nothing wrong with the routing or you would not get the cannot find View error (it has to get to the controller to return the view, which means routing works)

Answer (score 2):

MVC is expecting (by the convention) a view (with the same name as your action name in  any one of the folders (by default, But you can override this). You should have the view in any of the folders. That is the MVC convention. So add your view to that folder. You can add it by right clicking the `Return View()` statmenet in your action method and selecting `Add View` option. It will automatically add one view.

[image]

Or you can right click on the `Areas/Test/Views/Default1` folder and select Add View and save it with the same name as of your Action method. If you want to save it with a differnt name than the action name, you can use the View method like this

```
return View("MyOtherViewName");
```

Assuming that you added a `MyOtherViewName.cshtml` as your View in the `Areas/Test/Views/Default1` folder